Custom kernel hangs on boot, no error, no logs
I'm trying to compile QNAP's Linux 5.10 kernel because I need access to their proprietary file system.
After fixing (too many) errors I managed to get it to build. However, when I try to but it, I just get a black screen with a flashing cursor. If I remove quiet from the command line, it shows a boot logo and a flashing cursor below it, but again, no prints whatsoever. Journalctl doesn't even acknowledge that the kernel even started to boot. I've also attempted to redirect the output to a serial console but that doesn't show anything either.
Where do I even begin?

you're not even getting a "booting linux…" screen flickering through? you might not be properly loading the image? don't know how to boot stuff on a QNAP box. Where to start: make sure you can build an unmodified kernel, and boot it in Qemu, attach gdb to it and debug it. might not be worth it; there's nothing "custom" in a QNAP kernel that should be impossible to port to a mainline kernel, but I don't know what it is that you need.

Nope. Nothing. The last message is grub saying "loading initrd".
EDIT: QNAP has some proprietary LVM volume types that the mainline kernel doesn't.

You should enable debugging modules in kernel and also additional "debugging text", otherwise kernel output is very limited (usually mostly nothing). Also make sure that redirecting output to a serial console is supported by kernel (mostly dependent on the serial drivers and UART settings). I would also enable support for at least EXT3/EXT4 filesystems. Your first goal should be a booting system at all. Your /boot should be stored on an EXT3/EXT4 filesystem, just to make sure that it's working.

PS your faulty kernel should be independent from anything, it shall not need any additional files for boot, so make sure to compile all kernel boot arguments and needed modules into the kernel itself

Just updating that I've given up on this. I've extracted a prebuilt kernel and initrd from a working system and it also fails the same way when I try to run it on my system.
